# Criar nova DF baseado em critério de texto de certa coluna

Tags: r

eu tenho uma DF no seguinte modelo,

```
Data    Coluna 1    Coluna 2    Coluna 3
12/01/2016  82       88           abc
06/02/2016  30       76           abd
15/03/2016  9        74           abc_abc|1234
11/01/2016  43       48           abc_abc|1235
14/04/2016  21       100          abd_abd|1234
14/04/2016  28       21           abd_abd|1235
15/01/2016  50       16           abc_abc|1236
19/01/2016  14       66           abd_abd|1231
26/02/2016  14       73           abc_abc|1239
```

eu quero deixar as linhas somente onde na "Coluna 3" contenham o termo "abc", não é preciso fazer nenhuma outra função, somente este filtro mesmo, não necessariamente o "abc" estará no começo da coluna.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta usar o commando grepl

```
# Dados de exemplo
df <- data.frame(coluna1 = 1:5, coluna3 = c("abc", "abd", "abc_abc|1234", "abd_abd|1235", "avc-abc|1239"))
```

Com R Base:

```
df_nova <- df[grepl(pattern = "abc", x = df$coluna3, ignore.case = TRUE ),]

df_nova
>coluna1      coluna3
1       1          abc
3       3 abc_abc|1234
5       5 avc-abc|1239
```

Ou utilizando o pacote dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df_nova <- filter(df, grepl("abc", x = coluna3))
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Icaro! eu estava tentando usar o grepl mas admito que estava apanhando nos parâmetros, uma dúvida, porque é usado o "ignore.case = T"?

Comment: Para não fazer diferença entre maiúsculas e minusculas. Vale a pena lembrar que você pode e deve sempre usar a função "help" do próprio R e dar uma olhada na documentação das funções e seus parâmetros em caso de dúvida. Muitas vezes a resposta vai estar ali. Neste exemplo, basta digitar: help("grepl") ou ?grepl no console. Lembrando que isso serve para qualquer função.